# thrift java server - how to configure threads

Tags: java, thrift

I've got a following code that starts a thrift java server:

```
public class Server {

    public static void StartsimpleServer(GameService.Processor<GameServiceHandler> processor) {
        try {
            TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9090);
            TServer server = new TThreadPoolServer(new
              TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));

            System.out.println("Starting the multi thread server...");
            server.serve();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StartsimpleServer(new GameService.Processor<>( new GameServiceHandler()));
    }
}
```

I would like to set the number of maximum threads and other thread-related settings. How can I do that? I couldn't find any documentation concerning that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
TThreadPoolServer.Args a = new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(processor);
a.maxWorkerThreads(5);
```

Comment: Well, I guess, yes... but this syntax looks strange to me. Is `Args` a public inner class of TThreadPoolServer?

Comment: I've figured out how it is all configured. Strange that Args is an inner class, but it works anyway. Thanks!

Comment: It is. syntax is not strange, it's just that you are not used to it. `Args` is just in the namespace of `TThreadPoolServer`. It would be strange if we would use `java.lang.String` instead of `import` and just `String`, but it's the same thing...

Comment: You probably want to use something like `a.maxWorkerThreads(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2 );`